# The Mathematics of Putting TextBox Nicely on a Graph

Tags: computational-geometry

I have a line graph, Given some certain points on the graph, I wish to add some explanation on them, such as this:

[image]

Is there any mathematical algorithm that allows me to overlay my explanation textbox "nicely" on the graphs, avoiding self overlapping as far as possible?

I understand that "nicely" is quite a subjective term, but all I want is that those text fields must be laid out as evenly as possible.

Comment: For your sake, this is what graph theory is: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_theory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_label_placement